# Using existing JS function in angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I previously had a javascript function onclick="submitDynamicSku()" but we have recently started converting to Angular to use the controller to build off of and i want to be able to pass this function through since it is part of the my ng-repeat.

Example:

```
onclick="submitDynamicSku('x', document.getElementById('y').value, false, true);"
```

I wanted to try:

```
onclick="submitDynamicSku(product.sku, document.getElementById('{{ product.id').value, false, true);"
```

Current Code:

```
  $scope.submitSku = function(sku,id,false,true) {
    submitDynamicSku(sku, document.getElementById(id).value, false, true);

    function submitDynamicSku(sku, cnt, recurringOrder, viewCart) {
    jQuery("#dynamicAsstName").val(""); 
    jQuery("#dynamicSku").val(sku);
    jQuery("#dynamicSkuCount").val(cnt);
    jQuery("#setRecurringOrder").val(recurringOrder);
    jQuery("#viewCart").val(viewCart);
    if (viewCart == false) {
        jQuery("form[name='dynamic_add_to_cart_form']")
            .submit(function() {
                this.action = "";
                return true;
            });
    } 
    jQuery("form[name='dynamic_add_to_cart_form']").submit();       
}   
    }


<%--Angular Block--%>
                <li ng-repeat="product in products">
                    <div class="prod-img ">
                        <img ng-src="{{ product.imagePath }}" alt="{{ product.imageAlt }}" ng-class="{{ product.selector }}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="prod-info">

                        <h2>{{ product.name}}</h2>
                        <h3>{{ product.price }}</h3> 
                        <p>{{ product.description }}  </p>

                        <a class="fancybox" href="#prodDesc-{{product.id}}">More Information &#187;</a>
                        <div class="prod-cart">
                            <span class="qty-amt">QTY: <input value="1" id="{{ product.id }}"  /> BOX</span>

                            <button href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="submitSku(product.sku,product.id,false, true)">Add to Cart</button>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </li>
```

Comment: What is your desired result ??

Comment: Basically there is a <button> nested inside of the ng-repeat pulling information from my controller and I want that information to be inserted into this function.

Comment: Please share your html and controller script

Comment: so you dont want to call the function in the controller, but you want to pass parameters that are properties of the controller. just watch the little quotes on the first parameter

Comment: Updated my post to include full controller and html

Comment: No when i have the above code, the ng-repeat fails to load.

Answer (score 1):

Create the function inside your controller like this:

```
$scope.submitDynamicSku = function(pID){
   var elm = document.getElementById(pID);
   ....
}
```

Then in the HTML use ng-click: (assume you use ng-repeat on product)

```
ng-click="submitDynamicSku(product.id)"
```

Comment: I did this and it didn't work.
ng-click="submitDynamicSku()"

$scope.submitDynamicSku = function(){
      submitDynamicSku('{{ product.sku }}', document.getElementById('{{ product.id }}').value, false, true);

     
              }

Comment: try pass the all data you need (product.id product.sku) into the $scope function first with ng-click="submitDynamicSku(....,product.id,....), then inside the $scope  funtion, call your existing function with submitDynamicSku( ...product.id....)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have apply **ng-repeat** on div

**HTML:**

```
   <div ng-repeat="product in products ">
    <button ng-click="submitDynamicSku(product.sku,product.id,false, true)">{{product}}"</button>
    </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('products', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.products=[];
    $scope.submitDynamicSku = function(sku,id,false,true) {
       .......
    }
```

}]);

Comment: I placed my javascript function inside the $scope.submitDynamicSku and now it doesn't populate the ng-repeat

Comment: I was able to get it to work using this latest bu I had to remove the 'false','true' from the $scope.submitDynamicSku function.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Inside the Controller */
$scope.submitSku = function(sku,id) {
    submitDynamicSku(sku, id, false, true);
};

/* HTML */
<a ng-click="submitSku(product.sku, product.id);">...</a>
```